# "I will have somebody + inf"

Tags: grammar, future-tense, paraphrasing

I have this sentence on a paraphrasing exercise

> I'll ask Peter to help me move the furniture

I have to use the word **give** in this sentence

> I will have Peter __________ moving the furniture

I did not know how to complete it, it turned out the answer was

> I will have Peter **give me  a hand** moving the furniture

I am confused about this type of future

my first thought was that give should be actually **given** (I will have Peter given me a hand) as part of the future perfect, but apparently is not that type of future, and I was not able to do this exercise - I left it blank.

What is the grammar behind this ?

edit: I just have discovered there's this other Stack exchange site https://ell.stackexchange.com/ - if you consider this questions belongs there, please feel free to flag it

Comment: 'I will have Sally [do X]' takes a bare infinitive and possibly object (do the dishes / make dinner / phone you / sing / come over ...). 'I will have Sally give John a hand' uses a more complicated verbo-nominal structure (give a hand) and a transitive one at that, but the causative structure (have someone [do / sing / phone ...]) still requires a bare infinitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***to have somebody do something*** is a very common grammar pattern in English. And that's exactly what you've got there. It simply means *to get somebody to do something for you*. There is nothing in your sentence that has anything to do with the future perfect tense. Just learn this piece of grammar and you're good to go.

Example:

> I'll **have** one of my assistants **come** over to your place to fix it.