# "What do you have me do?" or "What do you have me TO do?"

Tags: subjunctives

"What do you have me do?" or perhaps "What do you have me **to** do?" Which one is correct and could you please anyone tell me the meaning of the phrase?  Thanks

Comment: Where did you hear/read that, in what context ([edit])? Did you perhaps mean to write *What **would** you have me (to) do?*?

Comment: What *meaning* are you trying to express? There's dated / formal *What would you have me do?* (What is it that you want me to do? - ***advise / command me***), and *What do you have for me to do?* (What task can I perform for you? - ***employ me, set me to work***).

Comment: from the movie "Golden age(about Elizabeth 1). She asks that question  to her advisers...

Comment: You should edit your question text to provide a link to the specific text that's confusing you. But almost certainly if if's Elizabeth I, she'll have been asking her council of advisers ***What would you have me do?*** - with the sense of ***What is your (considered, professional) advice as regards how I should proceed?*** It's not a usage you'd expect to hear in a modern colloquial context., but it *might* still occur naturally in some formal contexts.

Comment: According to https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Elizabeth-The-Golden-Age.html, there are no instances of `what do you have me do` in that movie, but there is one of `what would you have me do`. ELIZABETH: *What would you have me do? 'Cut out' half the people of England?*

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [“I will have somebody + inf”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148328/i-will-have-somebody-inf?rq=1) Also [What is difference between have/get/make someone do something?
](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/146862/what-is-difference-between-have-get-make-someone-do-something/146872)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: +1, with the possible additional shading of defensiveness or outrage, as in "What exactly do you geniuses think I should do in such a case [where my hand is forced, or all other outcomes are bad, etc.]?"

Comment: @Robusto: Indeed. Although I suspect that "defensive" implication would normally only apply in contexts where the speaker has already proposed one or more possible responses to some urgent situation, - responses which others have dismissed as impractical or otherwise undesirable. Effectively, the question as posed would then imply an unspoken but contextually obvious trailing ***...instead** (of my proposed response)*.

Comment: If it were *would*, which I'm quite confident is what it was, it would mean *what do you want me to do*. Actually closely related to the now pat phrase "if you will".

Comment: @FumbleFingers.....please tell what is used, instead of your given examples, in modern colloquial and formal contexts ?

Comment: I believe the actual answer is "What do you have **for** me **to** do?"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the tendency of the many comments to your question.

Userr2684291 directs our attention to a [scene](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Elizabeth-The-Golden-Age.html) in which Elizabeth I says the line "What would you have me do?"

As I read that scene, Elizabeth means to ask "What would you like me to do?" But her implication is rhetorical. She means that if you consider that question, "What would you have me do," you will realize that the proposed answer ("Cut out" half the people of England) is obviously a bad answer; and therefore Elizabeth has no real alternative to the plan she favors.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be clear, "What do you have me do?" and
"What do you have me to do?"
are both incorrect English.
I think @FumbleFingers has it right.

Comment: "What do you have me do?" is grammatical but only in rare contexts. If you've already started doing a job, but had a sudden moment of doubt, you could ask your employer "What do you have me do?" meaning "What do you normally have me do as a job?" with the habitual sense of the simple present.